# csv to shp python and formating a row

Tags: python, shapefile, csv, pyshp

I´m doing a script to convert csv to shp, but I want to format one of the columns.
It´s a string then I´d like to format like this

a[8:10]+' / '+a[11:16]+'  UTC'  being a the value in the column.

this is the code working

```
#Set up blank lists for data
nombre,codigo,y,x,time=[],[],[],[],[]

#read data from csv file and store in lists
with open('C:/archivecsvToRead.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    r = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for i,row in enumerate(r):
        if i > 0: #skip header
           nombre.append(row[0])
           codigo.append(row[1])
           y.append(float(row[2]))
           x.append(float(row[3]))
           time.append(row[4])


#Set up shapefile writer and create empty fields
w = shp.Writer(shp.POINT)
w.autoBalance = 1 #ensures gemoetry and attributes match
w.field('Longitud','F',10,8)
w.field('Latitud','F',10,8)
w.field('Date','D')
w.field('Date / Time','C',50)
w.field('ID','N')

#loop through the data and write the shapefile
for j,k in enumerate(x):
    w.point(k,y[j]) #write the geometry
    w.record(k,y[j],codigo[j], time[j], nombre[j]) #write the attributes

#Save shapefile
w.save(out_file)
```

How can I format the column time in order to show   a[8:10]+' / '+a[11:16]+'  UTC' being 'a' the value in the column ?

Comment: What shapefile/python module are you using?

Comment: [Pyshp](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) but what is a (a[8:10] etc.) ?

Comment: Hi The column time 4th is like "2014-05-30T16:32:39+0000" and I´d like to format it as '30 / 16:32 UTC' to show this in the label.

Comment: I´m using pyshp module

Comment: look for solution below

Answer (score 3):

> Hi The column time 4th is like "2014-05-30T16:32:39+0000" and I´d like to format it as '30 / 16:32 UTC' to show this in the label.

For that you can use [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression): you want to extract '30T16:32' from the string (This isn't geospatial but ...)

The pattern (regular expression to be matched) is `[0-9]+T[0-9]+:[0-9]+`or `\d+T\d+:\d+`(search for the regular expression numbers T numbers : numbers)

```
import re
a =  "2014-05-30T16:32:39+0000"
result = re.search(r'\d+T\d+:\d+',a)
print result.group()
'30T16:32'
print result.group()[0:2]
 '30'
print result.group()[3:]
'16:32'
print result.group()[0:2] + ' / ' + result.group()[3:] + 'UTC'
30 / 16:32 UTC
```

or

```
result = re.findall(r'\d+T\d+:\d+',a)
print result
['30T16:32']
# split the list
result = result[0].split('T')
print result[0] + ' / ' + result[1] + 'UTC'
30 / 16:32 UTC
```

or ... (many others pattern matching)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you could use the inbuilt Python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) library `strptime` method to read in the date/time string you have, but unfortunately it has issues when reading time zones from strings. Instead you can use the [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library to parse the date string, and the `datetime.strftime` library to write it out.

For example:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

s = "2014-05-30T16:32:39+0000" #This is an ISO 8601 datetime string
d = parser.parse(s) #recognizes the 8601 format without having to specify it, returns a datetime object
print datetime.strftime(d, "%d / %H:%M %Z") #prints out "30 / 16:32 UTC"
```

In the long run I think it is better to manipulate the datetime object as it gives a lot more control than using string manipulation.